# jq variable seems to hid original input

Tags: json, variables, jq

I'm trying to parse through some json and put certain sections into variables. I think I'm not understanding something about how variables work though.

Json:

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then using this jq:

```
.resources[] | select(.type == "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis") as $apis | { types: [.type], apis: $apis}
```

I get this:

```
{
  "types": [
    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
  ],
  "apis": {
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
  }
}
```

When I expected this:

```
{
  "types": [
    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas"
  ],
  "apis": {
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis"
  }
}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/4aeBOY9x6q

According to the variables section of the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.4/#Advancedfeatures)

> The expression exp as $x | ... means: for each value of expression
>   exp, run the rest of the pipeline with the entire original input, and
>   with $x set to that value. Thus as functions as something of a foreach
>   loop.

Which makes me think that .type should return from the original set not the filtered result I stored in $apis. Where is the disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

It's the `select` that is "hiding" some of the input.

To produce the output you expect, the simplest is not to use variables at all.  You could, for example, simply write:

```
.resources[].type
```

Comment: A later goal will be to build a result from different areas in the json so I'll be collecting variables like this:
select(.type == "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis") as $apis
select(.type == "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas") as $schemas
select(.type == "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations/tags") as $operationTags

then at the end I was hoping to build an object with the variables inside {$apis, $schemas}...etc

Comment: I’d suggest asking a new SO question, following the [mcve] guidelines.